# Construct an example matrix such that $\mathbf A \mathbf A^T$ is not invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

One theorem says:
A matrix $\mathbf A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ is:

- full column rank iif $\mathbf A^T \mathbf A$ is invertible
- full row rank iif $\mathbf A \mathbf A^T$ is invertible

[(proof link)](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/thm_full_rank_pd.html)

Now, I want to find just one example matrix $\mathbf A$, that is a singular matrix (i.e. degenerate or **not** full rank), such that $\mathbf A^T \mathbf A$ or $\mathbf A \mathbf A^T$ is **not** invertible and with a constrain that:

$\text{rank}(\mathbf A^T \mathbf A) < \text{rank}(\mathbf A)$ or $\text{rank}(\mathbf A \mathbf A^T) < \text{rank}(\mathbf A)$

I tried many random numbers to construct a small size of matrix (e.g. $4 \times 5$) using R language , but found no such matrix. Is this kind of degenerate matrix that makes $\mathbf A^T \mathbf A$ or $\mathbf A \mathbf A^T$ not invertible very unlikey to find (or it is impossilbe)? Any idea or method to construct such a matrix?

Comment: A Zero matrix $A$?

Comment: A proof of the theorem cited can be found on this link: [https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/thm_full_rank_pd.html](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/thm_full_rank_pd.html)

Comment: @John, the zero matrix is not invertible.

Comment: @John, forgot to mention a rank constrain for the example I would like to find. Already edited the post.

Comment: @Nameless, John is right, I want to find a invertible matrix, but my fault not mention another constrain. Already edited the post.

Comment: Neither inequality is possible; see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025469/prove-that-for-a-real-matrix-a-kera-kerata/1025472#1025472

Comment: @ Thanks @Travis, now I understand. Hopefully I can choose your comment as best answer because you are the first one to help me out.

Comment: @WeiZhong I'm glad you found it helpful, Wei. I'd write up a separate answer, but there are already good answers below that explain that argument well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is impossible.

From the relation $$rank(AA^T) = rank(A^T) - dim(N(A) \cap R(A^T)) $$.

The second term is always zero and the equality is always satisfied.

Comment: Thanks, but could you give me a link to explain the background theory behind this equation? Or a proof for this equation?

Comment: You can find it in page 210 of this book http://goo.gl/F6n07c

Comment: Exactly what I want, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

To generate matrices that are not full rank, start with a square matrix that is full rank (r > 1), and replace one row (or column) with a linear combinations of the other  rows (or columns).  That will reduce the rank by 1, in the case of row operations.

According to [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)), the rank of a real matrix is equal to the rank of its corresponding Gram matrix, so $$rank(A^T A) = rank(A A^T) = rank(A) = rank(A^T)$$

Comment: That's true, but I also want $\text{rank}(A A^T)<\text{rank}(A)$.

Comment: @WeiZhong You can't, as Louis said.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be a 3x2 matrix (with 3rd row being proportional to the 2nd row):

```
  A={{1, 2 }, 
     {2, 10}, 
     {3, 15}}.
```

Then $A.A^T$ is a 3x3 singular matrix:

```
  A.A^T={{5,  22,  33 }, 
         {22, 104, 156}, 
         {33, 156, 234}}
```

And $A^T.A$ is a 2x2 nonsigular matrix:

```
  A^T.A={{14, 67 }, 
         {67, 329}}.
```