# Global minimization and least squares

Tags: optimization, least-squares

I'm having a bit of trouble proving the following:

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ and define $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = ||Ax - b||^2$. How can I show that $x_*$ is a global minimizer for $f$ if and only if $x_*$ solves $A^TAx = A^Tb$?

I would appreciate any help proving this!

Comment: Have you see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440503/moore-penrose-pseudoinverse-solves-the-least-squares-problem-svd-framework/4444461#4444461)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show it you basically need two component

1. to show the least square solution is a local minimizer. To show it we could show the gradient vanishes. Since the gradient
   $$
   \partial_x f(x)= 2A^TAx-2A^Tb
   $$
   This is satisfied directly at $x_*$
2. to show the $f(x)$ is a convex function. We can show the Hessian is constant and positive definite
   $$
   \partial_{xx} f(x)= 2A^TA
   $$
   Thus $f(x)$ is convex, and the critical point $x_*$ is also a local minimizer.

For convex function all local minimizer is also global minimizer, QED.