# Understanding least squares solution and Moore-Penrose inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

Consider the matrix vector equation $Ax=b$ with
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\\
2 & 4
\end{pmatrix},
\quad
b=
\begin{pmatrix}
4\\
8
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Since the second row of matrix $A$ is a multiple of the first, $A^{-1}$ does not exist and the system has infinitely many solutions. The set of solutions is a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which satisfy
$$\label{abc}
x_1 + 2 x_2 = 4.
$$
However, calculating the Pseudo-Inverse $A^+$ of $A$ (using python or similar) is get a unique solution $x^+ = (0.8, 1.6)^T$.

As far as I understood correctly, the Pseudo-Inverse is an explicit way of calculating the least squares solution given by
$$
x^+ = \arg\min_x \frac{1}{2} || Ax - b||_2^2.
$$
This can be seen by using the singular value decomposition of $A$.

But obviously, all points satisfying $x_1+2x_2=4$ minimize the norm, hence there are infinitely many least squares solutions.

Why does the Pseudo-Inverse then give me a unique solution $x^+=(0.8, 1.6)^T$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if $Ax=b$ has a solution, then $x_*=A^+b$ is a particular solution and has the smallest $|\;|_2$-norm. See this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4444628/121671), for example, for more details.

Comment: Pseudo-Inverse is used if there is no unique solution i.e. when a solution does not exist or when there are infinitely many solutions. When a solution does not exist, pseudo-inverse gives you a result that minimise L2 norm of the error i.e. roughly what you have in your post. When there are infinitely many solutions, pseudo-inverse gives you solution with the lowest L2 norm.

Comment: Thank ou for the link. If I understood that right, my solution satisfies $|| (0.8, 1.6)^T ||_2 \leq || x^\prime ||_2$ for all other $x^\prime$ that lie on the line $x_1 + 2x_2 =4$. But doesn't this mean that $x^+$ is not the solution of the least squares, but rather of some regularized version $x^+ = \arg\min_x \frac{1}{2} || Ax-b||_2^2 + ||x||_2$? Because it no only minimized the error, but also the $||\cdot||_2$-norm.

Comment: @Sim: The *regularized* problem is not equivalent to the original mean squared problem. $x_+=A^+b$ is indeed a solution to $\operatorname{arg.min}\|Ax-b\|_2$, and amongst all solutions to such minimization problem, $x_+$ has minimal norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if $A\in \operatorname{mat}(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $b\in\mathbb{C}^n$,  $x_*=A^+b$, where $A^+$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse,  solves two problems simultaneously:

$$x_*=\operatorname{arg.min}\{\|x\|_2: x=\operatorname{arg.min}\|Ax-b\|_2\}$$
where $\|\;\|_2$ is the standard quadratic Euclidean norm, that is, if $x'$ is such that $\|Ax'-b\|_2=\min\{ \|Ay-b\|_2:y\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$, the $\|x_+\|_2\leq\|x'\|_2$.

Comment: Thank you, I think this cleared my confusion as it was not clear to me that the Moore-Penrose inverse solves the two minimization problems simultaneously.