# Validation of Normal Equations with Pseudo-Inverses

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, regression, pseudoinverse

In an exercise for uni I am asked to prove that $w^* \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is a solution to $\min_{w \in \mathbb{R}^d}\lVert y - Xw \rVert_{2}^{2}$ if and only if $X^\dagger X w^* = X^\dagger y$, where $X^\dagger$ is the pseudo-inverse of $X$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse).

My initial idea of solving this was by writing out the L2-norm expression, but I do not think this would help me, as this does not lead to an expression containing $X^\dagger$.

Could any of you help me with starting off this proof? thanks in advance!!

Comment: use the SVD definition of the pseudoinverse

Comment: Or use that $w$ is a solution iff $X^\dagger y - w\in Ker(X)$

Comment: In general there are infinitely many generalized inverse, each one will yield a solution to the OLS problem $w_g:=(A^*A)^gA^*y$. The Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse is a particular that gives a solution that has minimal norm $w_+=(A^*A)^+A^*y= A^+y=\operatorname{arg.min}\{\|x\|_2: x=\operatorname{arg.min}\|Ax-y\|_2\}$. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4444628/121671) is an explanation.