# Proof verification: Suppose A is a square matrix such that $A^T A= AA^T$. Show that the nullspace of $A^T$ is equal to the nullspace of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Suppose A is a square matrix such that $A^T A= AA^T$. Show that the nullspace of $A^T$ is equal to the nullspace of $A$.

Here is my attempt at a proof:

We must show that, given $A^T A= AA^T$:
$$Ax=0 , A^T y=0 \iff x=y, \forall x ,y$$
Now, suppose $x$ is in the nullspace of $A$ and $y$ in the nullspace of $A^T$:
$$Ax=0 , A^Ty=0$$
Multiplying the left most equation by $A^T$ and the rightmost equation by $A$:
$$A^TAx=0, AA^Ty = 0$$
As $A^T A= AA^T$, we have:
$$AA^Tx=0, A^TAy=0$$
At this point, I would like to claim that $x=y$, however I'm unsure if this is the case, as if we consider $AA^Tx=0$, it could be the case that $A^Tx$ is in the nullspace of $A$ rather $x$ being in the nullspace of $A^T$.

Thoughts?

Comment: You have to show that $\ker A=\ker A^T. $ i.e. $Ax=0\ \iff A^Tx=0$ for any $x.$ Do you are dealing with one element $x$ at a time. The formula $\langle B^TBx,x\rangle =\langle Bx,Bx\rangle$ should be useful.

Comment: No, $Ax=0,A^ty=0\iff x=y$ is absolutely _not_ what you have to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof:
We begin by showing $Ax=0 \Rightarrow A^T x =0$
$$Ax=0$$
$$A^TAx=0$$
As $A^TA = AA^T$,
$$AA^Tx=0$$
We now multiplt by $x^T$, noting that $x^T A = (A^Tx)^T$
$$x^T AA^Tx = (A^Tx)^T (A^Tx) = ||A^Tx||^2=0$$
Thus we have proven the initial statement, and proving its converse is done in a similar fashion. Q.E.D

Comment: more fun to note that the converse _follows_, since $A^{TT}=A$.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
\ker(A)=\ker(A^TA)=\ker(AA^T)=\ker(A^T)
$$
because of the assumption and this duplicate:

[Prove that for a real matrix $A$, $\ker(A) = \ker(A^TA)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025469/prove-that-for-a-real-matrix-a-kera-kerata).